# RSA was rejected by which journal?

Tags: public-key, history

Is it true that first time RSA algorithm  was rejected by a journal?

Comment: What research have you done?  Where did you hear this?  Are you thinking of Merkle's puzzles?

Comment: For what D.W. refers to, see [Ralph Merkle's own account](http://merkle.com/1974/)

Comment: I see from this site: 
https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/nataraj2/FamousRejections.pdf

Comment: The site is, at best, questionable.  For one, Dijkstra's "Go to statements considered harmful" was a letter to the CACM, not a paper. I don't believe there were formal reviews of letters to the editor.

Answer (score 6):

[The paper](http://cs.purdue.edu/homes/nataraj2/FamousRejections.pdf) you link to in your comment is a fictional paper where the author (inspired by experiences with reviews he got for his own papers) imagines how negative reviews to groundbreaking papers could have looked like. So its just [fun](http://bertrandmeyer.com/2009/08/14/rejection-letter-classic) ;)

AFAIK the RSA paper has never been rejected (but the very first paper of Ralph Merkle on public key crypto got rejected, as already mentioned in the comments).